# Consulta que genera excepcion ReportViewer, Visual Studio 2015, C#, MariaDB10

Tags: reportviewer

Estoy con el siguiente problema, tengo una aplicacion que se encarga de generar consultas mediante ReportViewer, la aplicacion se conecta a una Base de Datos MariaDB10 que maneja aproximadamente 19 millones de registros, los datos se almacenan mediante una aplicacion externa que recaba informacion de procesos en una planta.
Esa aplicación genera automaticamente su estructura de tablas, para el sistema de reportes solamente se requiere una tabla donde se guarda todos los datos de produccion, debido a que esos datos se encuentran en una sola tabla con solo dos campos para ordenarla lo que usamos es pivot para ordenar la informacion en funcion a requerimiento de cada reporte, uno de los reportes generados esta lanzando una excepcion al momento de generar repores parametrizados por fechas cuando se selecciona parametros de tiempos de mas de 20 dias el reporte lanza la excepcion, al revisar el codigo pudimos ver que la excepcion se genera justo despues de ejecutar la consulta pivot, ejecutamos esa consulta desde terminal directamente en el servidor de Base de Datos la consulta tardo un poco en generase pero al final no dio ningun error y pudo generar los resultados.

Incluyo la consulta mencionada y la linea donde genera el error es "MySqlDataReader hist = histoform.ExecuteReader();"

```
/*HISTORIAL FORMULA*/
string val = "", valu="";
int exitval = 0;                    
MySqlCommand histoform = new MySqlCommand("SELECT EVTTIME, SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.H_MNEMO = 'SET_CEMENTO' THEN ROUND(d.evtvalue) END) AS CEM, SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.H_MNEMO = 'SET_CARBONATO' THEN ROUND(d.evtvalue) END) AS CAR, SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.H_MNEMO = 'SK_SETCELULOSAVIRGEN' THEN ROUND(d.evtvalue) END) AS CVIR, SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.H_MNEMO = 'SK_SETCELULOSADKL' THEN ROUND(d.evtvalue) END) AS CDKL, SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.H_MNEMO = 'SK_SETPVA' THEN ROUND(d.evtvalue) END) AS PVA, SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.H_MNEMO = 'SK_SETHIDROFUGANTE' THEN ROUND(d.evtvalue) END) AS HID, SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.H_MNEMO = 'SET_LODO' THEN ROUND(d.evtvalue) END) AS LOD, SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.H_MNEMO = 'SET_FILLER' THEN ROUND(d.evtvalue) END) AS FIB, SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.H_MNEMO = 'SET_CELULOSA' THEN ROUND(d.evtvalue) END) AS DCEL, SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.H_MNEMO = 'SK_SETFORMULAOTROS' THEN ROUND(d.evtvalue) END) AS OTR, SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.H_MNEMO = 'SK_VALCODIGOFORMULMATPRIM' THEN ROUND(d.evtvalue) END) AS FORM FROM DATOSDT D,configuration c WHERE c.evtcellule = d.evtcellule AND EVTTIME BETWEEN '" + fecinic + "' AND '" + fecfinc + "' GROUP BY d.EVTTIME HAVING FORM IS NOT NULL ORDER BY d.EVTTIME DESC;", con.conected());
MySqlDataReader hist = histoform.ExecuteReader();
                    if (hist.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (hist.Read())
                        {
                            if (hist[1].ToString() != "" && hist[2].ToString() != "" && hist[3].ToString() != "" && hist[4].ToString() != "" && hist[5].ToString() != "" && hist[6].ToString() != "" && hist[7].ToString() != "" && hist[8].ToString() != "" && hist[9].ToString() != "" && hist[10].ToString() != "" && hist[11].ToString() != "")
                            {
                                if (hist[11].ToString() != "")
                                {
                                    if (hist[11].ToString() != val)
                                    {
                                        filas = dt.FORMULAHIST.NewRow();
                                        filas["FECHA"] = hist[0].ToString();
                                        filas["CEMENTO"] = hist[1].ToString();
                                        filas["CARBONATO"] = hist[2].ToString();
                                        filas["CELVIRGEN"] = hist[3].ToString();
                                        filas["CELDKL"] = hist[4].ToString();
                                        filas["PVA"] = hist[5].ToString();
                                        filas["HIDRO"] = hist[6].ToString();
                                        filas["LODO"] = hist[7].ToString();
                                        filas["FIBER"] = hist[8].ToString();
                                        filas["DESCCEL"] = hist[9].ToString();
                                        filas["OTRO"] = hist[10].ToString();
                                        filas["CODIGO"] = hist[11].ToString();
                                        dt.FORMULAHIST.Rows.Add(filas);
                                        exitval++;
                                    }
                                    val = hist[11].ToString();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        con.CerrarConexion();
                    }
```

Comment: Cual es la linea que genera el error? como sabes que es esa? va a ser muy dificil ayudarte asi, porque no tenemos ni una base para probar ni nada.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, estoy publicando todo el codigo del reporte:

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, quisiera publicar todo el codigo del reporte, pero parece que no tengo los permisos necesarios en este foro, si gustas podria enviarte el codigo de ese reporte a tu correo, hice una depuracion paso a paso por instruccion y al llegar a la linea "MySqlDataReader hist = histoform.ExecuteReader();" despues de unos 45 segundos pasa directamente al capturador de excepciones.

Comment: Eso no es necesario. Ni siquiera publicar todo el codigo. Solo lo esencial para entender el error. Apreta [edit] y agrega la info necesaria a la pregunta. Tambien pone exactamente el error que recibis.

Answer (score 2):

Hola ya pude solucionar mi problema, fue en los foros de msdn, de todos modos publico esta solucion en este post por si a alguien mas le pueda servir gracias por las respuestas.

> Matiza lo de que "la consulta tardo un poco en generase". ¿Cuánto es
>   "un poco"? Si es más de 30 segundos, casi seguro que el problema es
>   que el MySqlCommand generó un TimeOut. Se puede cambiar el valor
>   predeterminado de 30 segundos mediante la propiedad CommandTimeOut.
>
> histoform.CommandTimeOut = 120;
>
> En cualquiera de los casos parece un problema interno de ADO.NET, o de
>   los drivers de base de datos, o de la propia consulta. No creo que el
>   ReportViewer tenga nada que ver en el asunto.
>
> ```
> Proposed as answer by Juan MondragónModerator Monday, June 25, 2018 6:59 PM
> ```